# Can't see the logs for new relic on python service

Tags: python, newrelic

I'm trying to add the logs from my python service that runs on a docker

I followed this tutorial: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/python-agent/installation/standard-python-agent-install/

So I added this: `RUN newrelic-admin generate-config defcf97e23c0621d66d085a35e56f93fac788774 newrelic.ini`  to my docker file

and changed my entrypoint to run my python like this: `NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program python run.py`

and when I look at the logs on my pod I can see that the new relic is being used:

```
2022-09-29 14:09:43,457 (6/MainThread) newrelic.core.agent INFO - New Relic Python Agent (8.2.0.181)
```

But when I look at new relic in the new service I created for it in Services - APM I can't see it for some reason:

[image]

Am I looking at the wrong place or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might help you: stackoverflow.com/a/70611838/6104961